# Sampling in visual vm

Tags: java, performance

Can anyone explain the science behind the sampling functionality of [visualvm](https://visualvm.dev.java.net/features.html) ?

I would have thought that collecting the amount of CPU spent on each particular method would require instrumenting the application to be profiled, but it doesnt look like visualvm is doing any kind of instrumenting, so I'm curious to know how it's done...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like the new VisualVM-Sampler plugin gather performance and memory data by periodically polling the monitored application for thread dumps or memory histograms. Check [this article](http://java.dzone.com/announcements/visualvm-12-great-java) for more details.

Comment: Not sure specifically about VisualVM, but I think sampling the call stack(s) is generally the most common profiling method unless for some reason you really need accurate timings about very specific methods.

Answer (score 12):

It has a timer. 
When the timer fires, it copies the current contents of every thread's stack.
Then it translates the stack frames into method and object names, and records a count against the relative methods.

Because of this, it doesn't need to instrument the code, and is therefore very lightweight.
However, because it doesn't instrument the code is can miss short-running stuff.
So it's mostly useful either for tracking long-running performance problems, or to quickly identify a serious hot-spot in your code.

Answer (score -1):

When I start memory profiling JVisualVM spends a couple of seconds with instrumenting all the classes; at least that’s what it says it’s doing.

[image: JVisualVM performing instrumentation]

That sure looks like instrumentation to me. :)

Comment: I thought the OP was asking about CPU :)

Comment: The profiling plugin does instrument, but the sampling plugin does not.